# Heterogeneous initializer list

Tags: c++, c++17, initializer-list

I have a QueryField and Select helper classes used to construct SQL statements:

```
class QueryField
{
public:
    QueryField(std::string_view column)
        : m_column{ column }
    {
    }
    QueryField(std::string_view column, std::string_view alias)
        : m_column{ column }
        , m_alias{ alias }
    {
    }

private:
    std::string m_column;
    std::string m_alias;
};

class Select
{
public:

    Select(std::initializer_list<QueryField> fields)
    {
        for (auto & field : fields)
        {
            m_fields.emplace_back(std::move(field));
        }
    }

private:

    std::vector<QueryField> m_fields;
};
```

as seen from the code above Select is a collection of QueryField objects that can initialized like this:

```
Select{ QueryField{ "up.audit_option" "option" }, QueryField("uep.success"), QueryField("uep.failure") };
```

is it possible to eliminate the need of specifying QueryField explicitly and initialize Select object as follows?

```
Select{ { "up.audit_option" "option" }, "uep.success", "uep.failure" };
```

Comment: I tried to do it once and even asked on SO I guess. I'm pretty sure heterogenous init lists are currently impossible in cpp

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but you want a homogeneous (same types) not a heterogeneous (different types) list

Comment: What compiler are you using? Seems to compile fine to me? https://godbolt.org/z/XwgbD-? Or there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your solution, you can indeed drop the types, but you have to keep the braces:

```
Select{ { "up.audit_option" "option" }, {"uep.success"}, {"uep.failure"} }
```

Also be careful with initialized list: all the elements inside will be copied. Even if you move:

```
Select(std::initializer_list<QueryField> fields)
{
    for (auto & field : fields)
    {
        // Actually copy. No move is done.
        m_fields.emplace_back(std::move(field));
    }
}
```

No move is allowed since every elements in the initializer list are constant.

---

My preferred solution would be to drop `std::initializer_list` and be simple with simple case and more explicit with complex cases.

To allow true heterogenous parameters, I'll go with variadic templates:

```
template<typename... Args>
Select(Args&&... fields) :
    m_fields{QueryField{std::forward<Args>(args)}...} {}
```

If you want to keep the copy/move constructor, you must filter out some parameter types:

```
template<typename T, typename = void typename... Args>
struct is_not_copy_impl : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename Arg>
struct is_not_copy_impl<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<T, std::decay_t<Arg>>>, Arg> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
using is_not_copy = is_not_copy_impl<T, void, Args...>;

template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<!is_not_copy<Select, Args...>::value>* = nullptr>
Select(Args&&... fields) :
    m_fields{QueryField{std::forward<Args>(args)}...} {}
```

This code will move when a `QueryField` is passed, and construct a new one when a value of other type is passed.

The usage is this:

```
Select{
    QueryField{"up.audit_option" "option"},
    "uep.success",
    "uep.failure"
};
```

Comment: IMHO the constructor with variadic template is probably better, but it hides the copy and move constructors. Select select(other) and Select select(std::move(other)) stops compile. I declared both constructors as default but it does not help.

Comment: Probably the solution is make it not a constructor, but a function like MakeSelect(Args && ... fields) (like std::make_shared)

Comment: Ah yes you must filter out the move and copy constructor. I edited the answer